laravel new update, omits api.php and i can't use it
since the LARAVEL omits the API.PHP, when I define the routes, Route:: API Resource('students', Student Controller::class); and I access http://localhost:8000/api/students I get "The route API/students could not be found.",
i have tried a lot like: PHP artisan route :clear(cache and list), but it does not work

It doesn't omit the api.php, but you can set it up manually with https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/routing#api-routes . Can you show your exact route? It's hard to tell what you have here without proper formatting

you have to run php artisan install:api

Since Laravel 11 the api functionality doesn't come by default, you need to run the command php artisan install:api to create the routes/api.php file and install Laravel Sanctum.
You can learn more here: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/routing#api-routes
